# initializing an struct by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

How to use this `mxt_config *cfg` pointer to asign a value stored in an array?  The main idea is to assign an array value in order shifting the pointer to the next element of the struct.

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char F_Id;
  unsigned char V_Id;
  unsigned char Ve; 
  unsigned char Bu; 
  unsigned char Mat;
}InfoId_t;

struct mxt_config 
{
  InfoId_t id;
  unsigned char info_crc;
  unsigned char config_crc;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char line1[7] = {0x1,0x2,0x3, 0x4, 0x5,0x6, 0x7};
    mxt_config  *cfg = NULL;
    mxt_config  objcfg;
    cfg = &objcfg;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
    {
        (unsigned char*)&cfg->id + i = line1[i];
    }
}
```

Any help will be great because for sure there is something wrong, but I can't see what.

thank in advance

Comment: The "correct" way to do what you are asking would be: `std::memcpy(cfg, line_1, sizeof(line_1))`, but if I was code-reviewing this, I would ask a LOT of questions before letting that idea fly in the first place.

Comment: @Frank Even that might not be correct.  They need to asset that `sizeof(mxt_config) == sizeof(line1)`

Comment: The short answer is:  don't do this.  It's unsafe to assume what the in-memory-layout of the struct will be.  Instead, write a routine to explicitly set each member of the struct, by name, from its corresponding byte in the unsigned-char array, so that the compiler knows to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is something **wrong** in this approach:  while the standard ensures that the struct members will be stored in the expected order, it does not guaranteed they are contiguous (some padding could be added between some members).

> **[class.mem]/17:** Non-static data members of a class with
>   the same access control are allocated so that later members have
>   higher addresses within a class object. (...)
>   Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members
>   not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might
>   requirements for space for managing virtual functions and virtual base
>   classes.

The fact that all members are `unsigned char` reduces the risk (e.g. no alignment issue, no endianness surprises), but it's not guaranteed to work 100%. You should at least assert that the struct has the expected size, in order to avoid bad surprises:

```
assert(sizeof(mxt_config)==7);
```

If despite the risks you want to proceed, you'd need to correct your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
   *((unsigned char*)&cfg->id + i) = line1[i];     
}
```

Alternatively, you could opt for an algorithm, [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
copy (line1,  line1+7,  reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&cfg->id));
```